# mouse highlight max length

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to limit the length of text that a person can mouse highlight on my website, as part of a highlight->dbInsert feature.

So say for example I have the block of text, that is 900 chrs in length:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit Donec vitae posuere elit Nullam interdum dolor quis elementum mattis Aliquam ut dui non magna pulvinar iaculis et non odio Nullam quis pharetra nisi Vivamus elementum magna eu purus iaculis et interdum tortor fermentum Quisque mi sem interdum et porttitor sit amet dictum sit amet ex Quisque a elit dolor Duis lobortis libero id risus lobortis commodo sagittis sem lobortis Nam vel arcu ac eros imperdiet congue nec ac lectus Aenean elementum suscipit tellus et varius In mattis tortor porta laoreet lobortis Nulla mattis scelerisque ante id bibendum diam bibendum quis Etiam efficitur placerat orci nec pharetra Integer et pretium magnat venenatis nibh Nullam feugiat tempor turpis sed consequat Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit Ut in gravida lectus Cras feugiat tempor luctus Integer placerat eleifend lorem et vestibulum

And I only want to have 100 characters highlight, which would be:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit Donec vitae posuere elit Nullam interdum dolo

Here is the code that I am attempting to get to work:

```
    function getSelectedText() {
    var selectedText = "", sel;
    if (window.getSelection) {
        selectedText = "" + window.getSelection();
    } else if ( (sel = document.selection) && sel.type == "Text") {
        selectedText = sel.createRange().text;
    }
    var str = selectedText;
    if(str.length > 100) {
        selectedText = str.substring(0,100);
    }
    return selectedText;
}
```

While this code *does* cut the string/text off at the 100 character mark, it does not prevent the end user from highlighting more text via their mouse.

What I am wanting to do, in order to reduce confusion on user end of why their entire highlight was not inserted, is to actually *prevent the mouse* from selecting over one hundred characters.

How to do that is what I am asking for here I suppose, be it jquery or pure javascript.

Comment: selected text is an any text from the website or a text from some special block?

Comment: Yes, I should have mentioned that. I am using, for example: $('#content-area').mouseup(function() {

Comment: does selection always start from the beginning?

Comment: do not understand your question

Comment: can user select 100 chars from the middle of the text? 'Nam vel arcu ac eros imperdiet...', for example

Comment: Yes. Any text within the #content-area can be selected. (ps: interesting question, looking forward to an explanation of why that is a factor)